# ASP.NET GridView: How can we both postback when certain columns are clicked

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview

I have made a RowClickable GridView which allow us to postback if we click any row in the gridview.

The problem is i don't want postback to happen if i click in certain column of the gridview.

The way around can be even the postback happens i need to know the Column Index from which the postback is happening.

Does any body out there knows the Solution to it.

Please let me know if you have something similar,

Thanks,

Comment: Are you saying that you want the postback but that you don't want the postback? I.e., you want to respond to the click but you don't want the client to send a postback?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626989/asp-net-gridview-how-can-we-find-which-column-was-selected-in-gridview.

Comment: As per my comment on your previous question, please post your code that makes the row clickable.  Without that, we cannot advise you on a solution.

Comment: I do want that postback to happen but only if its happening from certain column. I have check/ check all checkbox in first column for which i don't want postback to happen as javascript is taking care of it, where as if gridview row is clicked some other column then column with checkbox then i need that postback to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem which is as follow:

We have to cancel the Event Bubbling from Checkbox so that it won't bubble up to the Gridview RowClicked event.

The way of canceling the event bubbling form checkbox is as follow:

cb.Attributes("onclick") = "event.cancelBubble=true;"

where cb is the checkbox.

Hope this will help others having same problem as i did,

Thanks,